# Multi language search

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an app that can be used in different languages. I would like the search to show all the results regardless of the language in which they are written.
For example: if I look for title=cat that also shows me those that contain ´chat´ (cat in French). Is this possible?
Or also that the search function by abbreviations or synonyms. How do I get that?

Here is my search code:

```
class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  const Search({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Search> createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  bool _readOnly = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    BlocProvider.of<resultCubit>(context)
        .getresult(film: filmEntity(id: widget.film.id));
    super.initState();
    _searchController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(onTap: () {
      FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

      if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
        currentFocus.unfocus();
      }
    }, child: Scaffold(
      body: BlocBuilder<resultCubit, resultState>(
          builder: (context, filmState) {
        if (filmState is resultLoaded) {
          List<filmEntity> result = filmState.films
              .where((film) =>
                  film.name!.contains(
                      _searchController.text) ||
                  film.type!.contains(
                      _searchController.text) ||)
              .toList();

          return CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverPadding(
                sliver: SliverAppBar(
                    floating: true,
                    snap: true,
                    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                    elevation: 0,
                    title: TextFormFieldCustom(
                      readOnly: _readOnly,
                      controller: _searchController,
                      hintText: 'Search ...',
                    
                    ),
                    ),
              ),
              result.isNotEmpty
                  ? SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return FilmTile(
                              film: result[index],
                              );
                        },
                        childCount: result.length,
                      ),
                    )
                  : const SliverEmptyWidget(),
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return const Scaffold(
              body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
        }
      }),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try with mapping those words in your local database or API level and then retrieve those data.

Comment: Can you write a little example please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [translator package](https://pub.dev/packages/translator)

```
final translator = GoogleTranslator();
// auto-detect the language of source text
var frenchTranslation = await translator.translate("cat", to: 'fr');
```

Step2: add it to your conditions

```
List<filmEntity> resultFr = filmState.films
          .where((film) =>
              film.name!.contains(
                  frenchTranslation) ||
              film.type!.contains(
                  frenchTranslation) ||)
          .toList();
```

and Finally Make a full list

```
MultiLanguageResult = [ ...result,
                        ...resultFr,
                        ...resultEs,
                        ...resultEn, ];
```

Comment: The Disclaimer says : This package is developed for educational purposes only. Can't use it on my app

Comment: @LaddybugLittle, you have a lot of choice for translating a text you can use them based on your needs, for example https://pub.dev/packages/google_translator do the same job with API, or you can use offline translation with https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_translation

Answer (score 0):

you can use the package 'language_toolkit' which provide multiple functionalities, including language detection, stemming and lemmatization, and synonym matching.